# Android thread doesn't work

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to run some data in a background thread in my application but when I tried in my app it didn't work.

Please help me.

Below is my code (what I tried so far):

```
package com.example.mos.androidclientmymobile;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private TextView textView;
  Handler handler=new Handler();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(9000);
          log("watinng for client");
          Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"yes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Socket socket =serverSocket.accept();
          log("a new client connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }

  public void log(final String message){
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
        textView.setText(message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've searched this topic but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Be more specific with "doesn't work." What should it be doing? What is it actually doing? Are you getting any errors? Can you post any stack traces? Have you been able to narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: logs doesent work and Toast

Comment: it means thread doesnt work

Comment: who can hellp me ,please help me

Comment: Comment Toast Line and then check

Comment: gui update ( `Toast...show()` ) is not allowed outside the gui thread. Put your toast inside the the log-run which is executed on gui-threat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //without the Looper.getMainLooper should work too
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        startProcessing();
    }

    private void startProcessing() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Loading data");
        t.start();
    }


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                log("a new client connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    public void log(final String message) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}

xml can be as simple as:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>

//if the above code works for you then the problem is in some other place, but not the handler or UI thread.
```